# Best practice for including 3rd party vendor native SDKs into a flutter app

Tags: flutter, dependencies, flutter-plugin, flutter-method-channel

We have a complex business application and interacts with several native SDK's. Many of these currently the provide Android and iOS SDKs but they are not going to provide Flutter SDKs as of yet.

What is the best practice for including them into our flutter project? Flutter [plugin](https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins) package seems like the obvious choice *but*

Should we create flutter plugin and wrap the native SDKs with method channels? Now should we do this for each native package (say we have more than 5).
This means that we will have 5 pubspec.yml, build.gradle, xcworkspaces etc. Manage the code, dependencies, tests in 3 stacks?

Or should we wrap all the SDKs into one giant plugin? Is there any other way to doing this elegantly.

Comment: I think it depends on your use case, In number of code and final size of app it will be approximately same for every case you try.

Comment: The 'normal' approach would be one plugin per SDK. Why would you be afraid of multiple pubspecs, etc? Eventually, if one of the vendors creates their own plugin (or pure Dart version) you can switch out yours for theirs. Voting to close as "opinion based".